# Number of boys in school

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle, percentages

We have $400$ students in a school. Every $20^{th}$ student failed at the end of the school year. Which was $2\%$ of schools girls and $10\%$ of schools boys.

The number of all boys attending the school is?

What I tried:

We know that every $20^{th}$ student fails, which means that $20$ students have failed. We also know that in these $20$ students are $2\%$ of all girls from the school and $10\%$ of all boys from the school. So we can make two equations like this: 
$$400 = b + g$$
$$20 = 0.1b + 0.02g$$

--I know the answer is $150$, but I got a different one.. if someone could point out an error in my logic, or just show how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equations are correct, so you apparently just made a mistake in solving the system.

I’d multiply the second equation by $10$ to get $200=b+0.2g$ and then subtract that from the first equation to get $200=0.8g$. Then $g=250$, so $b=400-250=150$.

Comment: Yeah, I made a stupid mistake, thanks :)

Comment: @Mykybo: It happens. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In your equation replace $g = 400 - b$ then you will get $b = 150$.